# Powershell Job freezes on opening SqlConnection

Tags: .net-3.5, powershell, powershell-2.0

My job seems to be hanging when opening an SQL connection. An example that reproduces the issue is as follows:

```
$myJob = start-job -ScriptBlock {
     $connection_string = [string]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2}; Password={3};Connection Timeout=5", "my_sql_server", "my_database", "my_user", "my_password");
     $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $connection_string;
     Write-Output "Opening Connection...";
     $connection.Open();
     Write-Output "Connection Opened!";
}
```

When I look at **$myJob**, it is always in the state of **Running**, with the output **"Opening Connection..."**. If I run the same code outside of a job block, it runs fine.

How do I correctly open SqlConnection inside of a job?

**EDIT**:

Here are the properties of $myJob:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\agprax>>> $myJob

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------                  
3               Administrator   Running    True            localhost             ...
```

Here is the job's output:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\agprax>>> Receive-Job $myJob
Opening Connection...
```

Comment: I ran your code here, and it works ok. There is something else in play that you are not telling.

Comment: Can you report the information you see when printing `$myJob` on the console? Please try `receive-job -job $myJob` for example.

Comment: I ran the code too, and it works fine. The `$myJob.state` is completed and `$myJob.jobstateinfo` as well. The only difference I've used trusted connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you running this job from?  It is worth noting there is a bug submitted on Connect that appears to be related to the issue you are having.

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/499499/adding-a-snapin-add-pssnapin-from-within-a-job-start-job-causes-job-to-hang-indefinitely

Comment: Your link seems to be a very similar bug to what I am having. I tried running this script in both Windows XP Pro and Windows 2003 Server with the same results. Given the fact that this bug has been on the back-burner for almost 2 years, and that only occurs in XP and Windows 2003 Server, I doubt it will ever get fixed.